# Spark Shell Import Automatically

Tags: apache-spark

I work a lot with avro files and everytime I start the spark shell I have to do these 5 imports

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

is it possible that these are automatically imported into the spark shell everytime I start the spark-shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717379/spark-how-to-run-spark-file-from-spark-shell).  Just include your imports in a file (`some_file`) and either specify it when starting spark-shell

```
spak-shell -i some_file
```

or run

```
scala>:load some_file
```

after spark-shell starts.