# Running the hive queries from a file through code via sparkcontext or hivecontext (not through command line)

Tags: apache-spark, hivecontext

Consider there are few hive queries in a file, my moto is to run the file using `hivecontext` or `sparkcontext`

Using command line I can do that by `hive -f 'filepath/filename'`
But I have to run it via code (`hivecontext` or `sparkcontext`)
Can anybody help on this?

For a single query I can use:

```
sparkContext.SQL('query')
```

But I have to run a file which is having queries.

Comment: Load file as string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark : how to run spark file from spark shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717379/spark-how-to-run-spark-file-from-spark-shell)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Spark/Scala:

```
queryFile = "path_of_your_file_queries"
Source.fromFile(queryFile, "utf-8").getLines().foreach(query => sparksql.sql(query))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your hql file some where like the below :

```
val Test = sqlContext.sql(open("file.hql").read())
```