# How to run an interactive spark application from spark-shell/spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark app that reads large data, loads it in memory and sets everything in between ready for user to query the dataframe in memory multiple times. Once a query is done, the user is prompted on the console to either continue with new set of input or quit the application.

I can do this very well on the IDE. However, can I run this interactive spark app from spark-shell?

I've used spark job server before to achieve multiple interactive querying on a memory loaded dataframe but not from a shell. Any pointers?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
Here is how the project jar looks and its packaged with all the other dependencies.

```
jar tf target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
my_home/
my_home/myhome/
my_home/myhome/App$$anonfun$foo$1.class
my_home/myhome/App$.class
my_home/myhome/App.class
my_home/myhome/Constants$.class
my_home/myhome/Constants.class
my_home/myhome/RecommendMatch$$anonfun$1.class
my_home/myhome/RecommendMatch$$anonfun$2.class
my_home/myhome/RecommendMatch$$anonfun$3.class
my_home/myhome/RecommendMatch$.class
my_home/myhome/RecommendMatch.class
```

and ran spark-shell with the following options

```
spark-shell -i my_home/myhome/RecommendMatch.class --master local --jars /Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but shell throws the following message on start up. The jars are loaded as per the environment shown at localhost:4040

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/05/16 10:10:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/16 10:10:06 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.101:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local, app id = local-1494909601904).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
That file does not exist

Welcome to
 ...
```

UPDATE 2 (using spark-submit)
Tried with full path to jar. Next, tried by copying project jar to bin location.

```
pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/bin

spark-submit --master local —-class my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch.class --jars myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/bin/—-class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-i <path_to_file>` option to run the scala code in your file or the scala shell `:load <path_to_file>` function.

Relevant Q&A: [Spark : how to run spark file from spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717379/spark-how-to-run-spark-file-from-spark-shell#29090241)

Comment: I saw this and attempted it. Please see my update above.

Comment: That style is for raw scala files using the same syntax that you'd use in the shell. You're basically just passing the commands via a file instead of typing them in the shell directly

Comment: ah thanks. So can I invoke spark-shell like this spark-shell --master local —-class my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch.class --jars /Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ? There is not file not found error but I'm still struggling with how to call the main function on this class

Answer (score 0):

The following command works to run an interactive spark application.

spark-submit /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/bin/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Note that is a uber jar built with the main class as entry point and all dependent libraries. Check out http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/