# Can we write Scala/Spark generic dynamically written code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create Spark Scala code which can read any file with different number of columns. Can i dynamically write scala/spark code and compile and execute it. do i really need SBT. Whats the perfect way to achive this goal.

when i run scala code using shell script or 
scalac code.scala it says

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/scala/examples$ ./survey.sh 
/usr/local/scala/examples/./survey.sh:6: error: not found: value spark
val survey = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("nullValue","NA").option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").option("mode","failfast").option("inferchema","true").load("/tmp/survey.csv")
             ^
/usr/local/scala/examples/./survey.sh:19: error: not found: type paste
:paste
 ^
/usr/local/scala/examples/./survey.sh:37: error: not found: value udf
val parseGenderUDF = udf( parseGender _ )
                     ^
three errors found
```

I want something like

dynamically generate file.scala code using shell script then complie it 
using

```
scalac file.scala
```

then execute it

```
scala file.scala
```

But is this possible.
what is the way to do it.

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples$ cat Survey.scala 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession}

object Survey {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
val spark= SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Survey")
  .getOrCreate()

val survey = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("nullValue","NA").option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").option("mode","failfast").option("inferchema","true").load("/tmp/survey.csv")
survey.show()
}
}
```

error when executed

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples$ scalac Survey.scala
    Survey.scala:1: error: object apache is not a member of package org
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession}
               ^
    Survey.scala:5: error: not found: value SparkSession
    val spark= SparkSession.builder
               ^
    two errors found
    hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples$
```

Comment: [Spark : how to run spark file from spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27717379)

Comment: This is working but taking time in starting the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090241) an alternative (by [cricket-007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007))

```
spark-shell -i survey.scala
```

But this takes time in configuring spark-shell it seems.

and this is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

To submit spark jobs, either you have to use [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) command or execute scala scripts in [spark-shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). [Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/) provides a REST API to submit spark jobs as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need create sparkSession exemple :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession}
val spark= SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("MYAPP")
  .getOrCreate()

val survey = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("nullValue","NA").option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").option("mode","failfast").option("inferchema","true").load("/tmp/survey.csv")
```

// for udf you need

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val parseGenderUDF = udf( parseGender _ )
```

i hop this help you

Comment: i tried what u said but this failed and i have updated it in question now